# Odd behavior when action assigned to BitBtn

Tags: delphi

I have an action assigned to a BitBtn and to a menu item.
The action's caption is '&Save' (has an accelerator on s). The shortcut for this action is 'Ctrl+S'.

When I run the app and press the S key the action is executed because of the accelerator. I think is pretty odd. The user sees that the keyboard shortcut is 'Ctrl+s' but still the action is executed with 's'. 
The program says something but does something else - this could be considered a full fledged bug. Right?

Plus that if there are multiple actions with similar shortcuts (ctrl+s, ctrl+shift+s, etc) or many menus with items with 's' as accelerator the user will be very very confused about why 's' does 'save file' and not 'save project'.

I want the action executed with 'Ctrl+s'. How do I do that?

(I know that I could edit button's caption to remove its accelerator' but if I reassign the action to the button I will have to remember to re-edit button's caption. There are too many actions and buttons there.).

Comment: If your caption is '&Save', that means it should be fired by Alt+S combinations and optionally by single S if no textedit box in the way. You are to choose if you want windows-standard accelerators (then drop Ctrl+S) or you custom (then drop accelerator). &S means Alt+S in Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is normal behaviour. That's how keyboard accelerators have always worked and are meant to work. The way to stop the <kbd>S</kbd> key invoking a button click is to remove the accelerator.

Comment: Damn it! I hoped for a more 'automated' solution :)

Comment: You could no doubt subvert the way accelerators work but then you'd be inventing your own UI standard that differed from the platform standard. I know that I routinely press just the underlined accelerator key on dialog boxes. For example when I see a Windows Yes/No dialog box I will press the `Y` key and expect the dialog to go away.

Comment: "when I see a Windows Yes/No dialog box I will press the Y key and expect the dialog to go away" - Yes! Totally totally agree with you. But my case is a bit different.

Comment: If there are multiple actions with similar shortcuts (ctrl+s, ctrl+shift+s, etc) or many menus with items with 's' as accelerator the user will be very very confused about why 's' does 'save file' and not 'save project'.

Comment: ok... accepted. I just wanted a confirmation that it cannot be done otherwise.

Comment: @Altar, if you have multiple menu items with the same accelerator key at the same level, you should either set the TMenu(Item).AutoHotKeys to maAutomatic or call TMenuItem.RethinkHokeys to resolve that.

Comment: @Uwe. No. The items with the same accelerator are in different menus. However, because of this, there are multiple buttons on my interface that have the same accelerator.

Comment: @Altar you should probably rethink your user experience, as you are deviating from the standard. Users expect  Windows apps to adhere to that standard. Deviating can be done, but only in extreme circumstances.